# Keras normalization pollutes data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, normalization

I've written simple digit recognition model that was fed with images from MNIST and I wanted to use this model to predict my own digits but I bumped into problems with normalization.

To normalize images from MNIST I used:

```
x_train = keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1) # shape = (60000, 28, 28)
```

but when I'm trying to do the same with my own image:

```
my_digit = cv2.imread("three.jpg") # shape = (28, 28, 3)
my_digit = cv2.cvtColor(my_digit, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # shape = (28, 28)
my_digits = np.array([my_digit]) # shape = (1, 28, 28)
my_digits = keras.utils.normalize(my_digits, axis=1)
```

after normalization using keras image is getting a bit dirty:
[image with keras' normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9zgP.png)

when I remove :

```
my_digits = keras.utils.normalize(my_digits, axis=1)
```

then image is fine [image without keras' normalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck7JB.png)

The 'solution' I found is dividing every element by 255 like that:

```
my_digit = np.divide(my_digit, 255)
```

then the image looks fine - like before normalization

EDIT:
Before normalization x_train(MNIST dataset) its dtype is uint8, after normalization it is float64. For my image - before normalization(utils.keras) its dtype is uint8 and after normalization it is float64. It is also the same when I normalize my digit by diving every item by 255 - I mean uint8 before and float64 after.

I'm wondering why if I normalize my own images(images from MNIST after keras.utils.normalization looks as good as before normalization) manually then they look ok but when I use keras.utils.normalization then I'm getting some 'pollutions'

Comment: Please check the datatypes of the `x_train` and `my_digit`/`my_digits` data before and after the normalization, please, and add this info to the post.

Comment: I've checked it and unfortunatelly it looks like dtypes are fine. I've edited the post.